# Webscraping using python and beautifulsoup is not returning all requested data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this site for all the NSNs
https://www.iso-group.com/fsg/Mechanical-Power-Transmission-Equipment/Gears-Pulleys-Sprockets-Transmission-Chain/3020_GEAR-SPUR/1
using the following code

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib3

 from datetime import datetime, timedelta



from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

f = open("GEAR SPUR.csv", "w")

headers = "NSN, Part_Name, \n"
f.write(headers)

for page in range(69):
    NSNurl = 'https://www.iso-group.com/fsg/Gears-Pulleys-Sprockets-Transmission-Chain/Mechanical-Power-Transmission-Equipment/3020_GEAR-SPUR/'.format(page)

    uClient = requests.get(NSNurl)

    page_html = uClient.content

    # close client
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    container = page_soup.find_all("table", {"class": "table table-hover table-responsive"})


   for container1 in container:    #container1 is <td> element
       NSN = container1.find('td')
       nsn = container1.find('a') #get the anchor from the <td>
       if nsn is not None:        #if an anchor is found
          NSN = nsn.contents[0]
          print(nsn.contents[0]) #print it
       else:
          Nomenclature = container1.text
          print(NSN) 

          f.write(NSN + "," + Nomenclature.replace(",",""))
  f.close()
```

It worked for only the first number and it returned is the same number over and over again. These are the output before I terminated it

```
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
 3020-00-449-0495 - 3020004490495
```

why is it doing this and How can I fix it to return all the numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Your url doesn't have a placeholder in the string for your page number to go into. You need to have `{}` in the string where you want the page number to be, otherwise `.format(page)` does nothing. Currently your url never changes. Based on your comment, change your url to be

```
NSNurl = 'https://www.iso-group.com/fsg/Gears-Pulleys-Sprockets-Transmission-Chain/Mechanical-Power-Transmission-Equipment/3020_GEAR-SPUR/{}'.format(page)
```

The curly braces acts a placeholder, and when you do `.format` the values are subsituted for placeholder. Have a look [here](https://pyformat.info/) for more info on formatting strings.

I would also see Roman's answer around the scraping of the markup

A further issue you might come across is your actual code for getting NSN/nsn/Nomenclature is a bit hard to decipher, and will only actually save to your csv if `nsn is None`, even though you are printing the output for for both cases.

Hopefully this is enough pointers for you to fix your code. Please clarify the question if you are still having issues.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I forgot to indent to properly indent the code when i tranfered it here. I have duplicated the indentation now. what do you mean by having {} in the string where the page goes? are you talking about a separate declaration of pages?

Comment: @learner101 I have updated my answer - your url never changes, where do you expect the 0-68 from your loop to go in the url text?

Comment: yes. it goes in the url. for example     NSNurl = 'https://www.iso-group.com/fsg/Gears-Pulleys-Sprockets-Transmission-Chain/Mechanical-Power-Transmission-Equipment/3020_GEAR-SPUR/2 (then 3,4,5,6,....)

Comment: @learner101 have a go changing the url as in my answer and see if you get further. Do take into account Roman's point about how to properly parse the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue you have in this line:

`container = page_soup.find_all("table", {"class": "table table-hover table-responsive"})`

You are trying to iterate through `container`, but it's length is 1.

You probably should modify line like this:

`container = page_soup.find("table", {"class": "table table-hover table-responsive"}).find_all('tr')`